# problema al recibir datos atraves de ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

estoy intentando enviar por ajax unos datos pero no logro recibirlos en php y luego mostrarlos, les dejo el código para el que me pueda ayudar, seguro que la solución es muy simple pero yo soy muy novato y no logro identificar.

html

```html
este es el boton o enlace que inicia la función de js.

<td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-control-field jsgrid-align-center">
<a href="javaScript:Void(0)" class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect waves-light btnDetalleFactura" idfactura="<?= $consecutivo ?>" idnegocio="<?= $idnegocio ?>"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a>
</td>

<div id="detallesfactura" class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"><?echo $detallefactura ." ". $idnegocioA;?></h4>
</div>
```

esta es la función de ajax que envia los datos a la pagina php.

```js
$(".btnDetalleFactura").click(function(){

document.getElementById('facturas').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('detallesfactura').style.display = 'block';

$.ajax({

    url: "?page=ventasajax",
    type: "GET",
    data: {save: "1", detalleFactura: $(this).attr("idfactura"), idnegocio: $(this).attr("idnegocio")}


    });

});
```

```
codigo de php que recibe los datos.

<? 
if (isset($_GET['save'])) {

    $detallefactura = $_GET['detalleFactura'];
    $idnegocioA = $_GET['idnegocio'];

}
?>
```

al verificar por consola me indica que los datos llegan correctamente, pero igualmente no imprime nada.

> user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142
>   Safari/537.36 x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest page: ventasajax save:
>   1 detalleFactura: 1 idnegocio: 2743.

Comment: Puedes agregar la página dónde recibes los datos del GET y dónde quieres visualizar la información?

Comment: claro amigo esta en la misma pagina donde esta el botón que envia los datos a la función de ajax. <div id="detallesfactura" class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"><?echo $detallefactura ." ". $idnegocioA;?></h4>
</div>

Comment: Ya intentaste imprimir en el php `echo $_GET['save']` y en el ajax `$.ajax({

    url: "?page=ventasajax",
    type: "GET",
    data: {save: "1", detalleFactura: $(this).attr("idfactura"), idnegocio: $(this).attr("idnegocio")}


    })
.done(function(respuesta){ console.log(respuesta);}) //en esta parte recibes la repsuesta del servidor
`
recibir la respuesta para ver si te esta imprimiendo en este caso **1**?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando envías datos al servidor para espera datos serializados así dato1=1&dato2=2, pero que al mandarlos serializados en formato json no los manda a la variable $_POST, tienes que leerlos directo del input de php, pero aguas tienes que serializados antes de enviarlos con json.stringify y los recibes con $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

```
$.ajax({
    url: "?page=ventasajax",
    type: "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify({save: "1", detalleFactura: $(this).attr("idfactura"), idnegocio: $(this).attr("idnegocio")})
    });
});
```

Y en php

```
if (isset($_GET['save'])) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
    $detallefactura = $data['detalleFactura'];
    $idnegocioA = $data['idnegocio'];

}
```

manda toda tu datos en formato json, si intentas mandar parte tradicional y parte json no funcionara lo que te digo tendrías procesarlo diferente, osea tendrías que serializar el json y mandarlo dentro de una variable algo asi dato1=1&datajson={data: uno, data2: 3}